# Should followers still get the same email settings?

Tags: user-expectation, email, subscription

In our platform, we can a concept of "people" that belong to "organizations." These people can have followers. Followers are assigned to people within our internal platform.

If a person under an organization has been subscribed to certain emails, their followers then are automatically subscribed to the same emails.

But if a person leaves the organization (because they no longer work there), this person doesn't necessarily get removed from the organization, but their email preferences get blocked - ie, they will no longer receive any of the emails they were originally subscribed to.

What ideally should happen to their followers? Should their followers also no longer get the same emails? ie, should their followers automatically get unsubscribed?

Answer (score 1):

**"But I was reading that"**

I think it's important to view Followers as individuals with their own needs and preferences, rather than a subsidiary of "People".

People follow influencers because they want to know what the influencer knows. There's a saying in social media that people don't share your post because they like *you*, they share because they want to look smart or funny or cool to their own audience. They're more connected to the content than to the person who introduced it to them. (Fan appreciation posts are different, but I don't suspect that applies to your case.)

So, after a "person" leaves an organization, it's very possible that their followers still might value what they were reading, so as to become more like the person they were following. Cutting them off from valuable information might feel like they're being punished for something they had no control over.

Since they are individuals with their own needs and preferences, though, you might not want to automatically opt them into an email list based on someone else's actions. You're teaching them that following someone means more possibly unwanted content in their inbox, so they might be disinclined to follow more People, and that might be an important metric for you.

**Why not give them a choice?** When a Person subscribes to an email, perhaps you could send an email to their followers. "Kevin Yi has followed Tech Trends, would you like to subscribe as well?" Let them opt in until they opt out, no need to suggest they leave when Kevin leaves.

Answer (score 0):

I would think that follows also no longer get the same email. By following the person, you are following the person and their preferences, not the organization they belong to. If you wish to follow just the organization, maybe add a feature to follow an organization directly so that even if the person leaves, the follower can still receive those emails. Otherwise, if the person gets unsubscribed, so should the follower.